# Selecting URLs to print from multiple DIVs

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am new to programming and Python.

I am using Python 2.7 with BeautifulSoup to extract all the URLs from a certain search results page.

The page is https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC= (might take a while to load)

The code surrounding the URL is as follows:-

```
<div id="content_findResults">
<div id="content_column1">
<h1 id="ctl00_ctl45_g_1e68d58d_9902_48ce_b555_5d3eb35d5624_ctl00_headingCriteria">Showing Search Results for 'OH'</h1>
<h2 id="ctl00_ctl45_g_1e68d58d_9902_48ce_b555_5d3eb35d5624_ctl00_headingResults">Your search returned 18440 results</h2>
<h4 id="ctl00_ctl45_g_1e68d58d_9902_48ce_b555_5d3eb35d5624_ctl00_headingYourSearch">Your search: 'State: OH'</h4>

<ul id="ctl00_ctl45_g_1e68d58d_9902_48ce_b555_5d3eb35d5624_ctl00_resultsList">
<li>
<a href="**/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&amp;pID=10727**">Janet Gilligan Abaray</a></li>
<li>
<a href="**/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&amp;pID=26507**">Kenneth Pascal Abbarno</a></li>
```

I am lost as to what to use to make sure I can extract the URls from within those multiple DIVs, UL and LI.

I am using the following:

```
def oh_crawler():
    url = "https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC="
    code = requests.get(url)
    text = code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for link in soup.find('div',{'id':'content_findResult', 'id':'content_column1'},'a'):
            href = 'https://www.ohiobar.org' + link.get('href')
            print (href)
```

Obviously it isn't working.

Please advise on how I can select the URLs to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all `a` elements containing `MemberProfile` in the `href` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC='

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'}

    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    for link in soup.select("div#content_findResults div#content_column1 ul li a[href*=MemberProfile]"):
        print link.get("href")
```

Here, I'm using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate the `a` elements.

Prints:

```
/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&pID=10727
/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&pID=26507
...
/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&pID=17139
/Pages/MemberProfile.aspx?sST=OH&pID=57207
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A couple questions, if I may please:-

1. From where do I get the user-agent information to enter?

2. The URL I posted has over 18K URLs, but the code only returned about 1600. How do I extract 'all' the URLs from the page. There is no pagination and all the URLs are on that single page only.

Many thanks once again

Comment: @pb_ng user agent is probably not required to be set. I've just used a template for the similar requests+bs4 code snippets. Your second question would be better to solve in a separate thread in case you have difficulties. Consider creating a new question and throw me a link here.

Comment: @pb_ng well, may be I know the answer right away. Install `lxml` and try with `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")`. Lmk whether it helped or not. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that Alex, but it got the same number of results. Anything else I should try?

Comment: @pb_ng interesting, I'm getting 18440. Are you executing the same exact code as provided in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex - I just appended the base URL of the website to link.get, so it now is `print 'https://www.ohiobar.org' + link.get("href")` That shouldn't cause any issues I guess. Would it?

Comment: @pb_ng looks ok, but I'd use `urlparse.urljoin()` instead of simple concatenating.

Comment: Could you please show me how and where to use the `urlparse.urljoin()` but the main thing is why am I not getting all the 18K URLs. This is the entire code pasted. Could you please check if I have messed up something in there? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d81c9b3c14cff4943d7

Comment: @pb_ng the code looks ok to me and works on my end. It could be some sort of an anti-web-scraping technique used by the target site..can you try the same code but from a different machine (with a different ip address)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alec - I tried running the program with a proxy but it fetched the same no of results, i.e. - 1622. Not sure why it is not fetching all the 18,000+ URLs :(